# Can I create a custom ratio based on two fields in Google Data Studio?

Tags: google-analytics, google-data-studio

I'm trying to create a custom ratio in Google Data Studio that is:

```
'sessions with a particular event' / 'all sessions'
```

Can anyone tell me if this is possible?

I tried using a calculated field, but this ratio relies on both metrics and dimensions, so that wasn't possible.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than "sessions with a particular event", use total events / all sessions, and then create a filter to restrict it to the particular event you are interested in.